# yii2 phpDoc- word order

Tags: yii2, phpdoc

Why in yii2 phpDoc annotation in views we can see such word order

```
 * @var $width integer
```

and in class's methods such word order

```
 * @param integer $width
```

Why doesn't the second example have such form

```
 * @param $width integer
```

Comment: Hi, if you find some answer helpful and it solve your problem check it as correct answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for this tag is

```
@param [Type] [name] [<description>]
```

So declaration where type declared after parameter name is incorrect, but as you see it works the same so i guess that it has no difference but better to use syntax.